# Tomcat not connecting to SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, jdbc

I have a webapp running under Tomcat, connecting to SQL Server Express via jdbc for data. Works well on the Vista machine that I first used for development. I've been trying to move it to a Windows 7 machine where it will run live, but it doesn't work, and I've run out of things to check. Need help. The installations (my part) seem to be exactly the same on both machines. But I should mention that the new machine (where it doesn't work) has another application running that connects to the same or another version of SQL Server. Here's the error from the Tomcat log.

```
Allvarlig: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at nu.isr.hll.webshop.core.HLListProcess.initialize(HLListProcess.java:73)
    at nu.isr.hll.webshop.servlets.HLListServlet.init(HLListServlet.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1813)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jdbc driver wasn't loading.

Looks like the problem comes down to a buggy Microsoft jdbc driver. According to the documentation, sqljdbc4 does not require explicit driver registration. Version 4 should do that automatically. Works fine on the Microsoft Vista dev machine. But it didn't work when I installed the app on Windows 7 (They are two different OS here, and I'm guessing that matters.)

Had to include Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

Now it works!

Comment: I'm going to add a caveat here. A good reason to use jdbc is that you don't need to rewrite your code to switch database systems. Doing something based on a nonstandard Microsoft feature is a bad idea in the first place. I've been thinking about that for the past hour, wondering why I fell for it.

Comment: I think now this post and solution offers an excellent resource for people working with jdbc and SQL Server, many of whom will run into the same problem.

Comment: I think you need to work on your professional human interaction skills before spending much time in technical discussion forums; also sharpen up the logic skills. People posting for help on something aren't bragging about it. Thus, your cheap shots just don't hit the mark. I could explain further why this is a good post, but I don't think you're capable of understanding it just now.